# D3 Charts, How to iterate through Json data NOT from file?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to pass JSON data (from an AJAX call) into a function that uses D3 charts to iterate through the data. I am NOT passing the URL to a Json file, I am passing the DATA from a Json that is returned from an AJAX call. Every time I do this, however, the 'data' in the callback is undefined and won't let me iterate through it. How do I manage this?  I just want to iterate through the JSON data and draw things according to it.

Here's the example code:

```
drawLine(jsonData)

function drawLine(chartData) {
    d3.json(chartData, function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDateD3(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
        });

    // DO STUFF PAST HERE TO DATA

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use `d3.json` if you're actually doing an AJAX call. If you have the data already, the code should look like this.

```
function drawLine(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDateD3(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

  // DO STUFF PAST HERE TO DATA
}
```