# "Cartograms with d3 " how to use data from MySQL?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js, cartogram

demo is here：[a d3-cartogram demo](http://prag.ma/code/d3-cartogram/#popest/2010)

It gets data from a .csv file .
how could I use data from MySQL or static data in HTML File?

I tried some ways but didn't work.

Comment: Share whatever you have tried, Add it into your question

Comment: You need to have a server side which will query the result and send to the browser via ajax

Comment: No you don't. You can simply pass the data as an array to the data() or datum() function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 Charts, How to iterate through Json data NOT from file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582556/d3-charts-how-to-iterate-through-json-data-not-from-file)

Answer (score 1):

Put the data in JS, HTML or anywhere and pass it to a selection's data() function like so:

```
d3.selectAll('#mydiv')
  .data([1, 2, 3])
  .enter()
  .append('div')
```

The array here could as well be passed as argument, fetched from a hidden html element or you can render it directly into the JavaScript.